# camel suspends route using control bus

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have camel route which suspends the route using control bus on exception.

```
onException(Exception.class).maximumRedeliveries(1).onRedeliveryRef("controlBusProcessor");
from("quartz2://myGroup/myTimerName?trigger.repeatInterval=2000&trigger.repeatCount=0")
                    .routeId("myRoute")
                    .process(simpleProcessor)
                    .to("stream:out")
```

The route initially calls a simple processor which raises an `Exception`, the `onException` has a `redeliveryRef` which calls  a control bus processor which suspends the route, however it still calls simple processor to redeliver the message.

If the route is suspended, why is simple processor is still called, should it not wait until the route resumes?

Answer (score 1):

No the route will complete its in-flight messages before being suspended. In your custom redelivery processor, you can mark the exchange to stop continue routing by setting the property on the exchange with `Exchange.STOP=true`.

See how the `StopProcessor` does that: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/StopProcessor.java

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the redelivery starts at the point of failure which is at `.process(simpleProcessor`). But if you only want to suspend the route why not just add `.onException(Exception.class).to("controlBusProcessor")`